# What can I do if delimiter of csv is appear in value?

Tags: csv

Suppose, my csv file contains

```
"item_name","price","description"
mobile,500$,It has many features (e.g., camera, big display, etc)
```

I want to load this csv data file in mysql database using mysql command like

```
load data local infile 'file.csv' into table table
 fields terminated by ','
 lines terminated by '\n'
 (column1, column2, column3,...)
```

You can also say to use enclosing each value by `"` and using `enclosed by '"'` option of mysql. But enclosing each value is overhead to me.

I can enclose only `description` value if there is a solution to read this type of csv where one column is enclosed by `"` but not all.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that is _not a CSV file_, exactly because the unquoted field contains the field delimiter. A properly formatted CSV file would double quote the problematic field. No dedicated CSV parser would be able to parse the file as it is currently presented. The MySQL loading is not a CSV parser however, and even quoting the last field would not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the field delimiter from commas to something that is not otherwise present in the file.  If you have control over what creates the CSV file, then this should not be too difficult.

With [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/), this can be done if the last field is properly quoted:

```
$ cat file.csv
"item_name","price","description"
mobile,500$,"It has many features (e.g., camera, big display, etc)"

$ csvformat -D@ file.csv
item_name@price@description
mobile@500$@It has many features (e.g., camera, big display, etc)
```

Or, without `csvformat`, assuming that the first two commas on each line are true delimiters:

```
$ sed -e 's/,/@/' -e 's/,/@/' file.csv
```

This does not require the last field to be quoted.

Redirect this to a new file, and then use

```
load data local infile 'newfile.csv' into table table
 fields terminated by '@'
 lines terminated by '\n'
 (column1, column2, column3,...)
```

Comment: Without csvkit, on the OP's input, one can always do `sed 's/,/@/;s/,/@/'` to replace the first two `,` with `@`

Comment: Is there any problem if I will use `|` as delimiter instead of `@`?

Comment: @alhelal You may choose any character that is not already part of the file's data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it a *complex field* and I'm personally for encoding them, for example, in `base64`,

```
$ echo "It has many features (e.g., camera, big display, etc)"  | base64
SXQgaGFzIG1hbnkgZmVhdHVyZXMgKGUuZy4sIGNhbWVyYSwgYmlnIGRpc3BsYXksIGV0YykK
```

But there is of course pros and cons of doing so.

Comment: Then how do I extract the original data?